# Writing strings with chars like "ñ" to a txt file

Tags: java, string, file, character-encoding

Im having a strange issue trying to write in text files with strings which contain characters like "ñ", "á".. and so on. Let me first show you my little piece of code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

    String content = "whatever";

    int c;
    c = System.in.read();        
    content = content + (char)c;

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();

}

}
```

In this example, im just reading a char from the keyboard input and appending it to a given string; then writting the final string into a txt. The problem is that if I type an "ñ" for example (i have a Spanish layout keyboard), when i check the txt, it shows a strange char "¤" where there should be a "ñ", that is, the content of the file is "whatever¤". The same happens with "ç", "ú"..etc. However it writes it fine ("whateverñ") if i just forget about the keyboard input and i write:

```
...
String content = "whateverñ";
...
```

or

```
...
content = content + "ñ";
...
```

It makes me think that there might be something wrong with the read() method? Or maybe im using it wrongly? or should i use a different method to get the keyboard input? or..? Im a bit lost here.

(Im using the jdk 7u45 @ Windows 7 Pro x64)

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Are you opening the file with notepad? Try wordpad.

Comment: Also, try `System.out.println(content);` before writing it to a file please.

Comment: You should specify which encoding you want to use for your file. UTF-8 is generally a good choice or if you will only use windows you can also try cp-1252. And you can also use the helper methods in Files instead of a Writer: `Files.write(Paths.get("filename.txt"), content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: Im using notepadd++ both for coding and for watching txt files. Worpad shows the same weird character. Also, i already tried System.out.println(content) and it prints the right string in the console

Comment: Use a hex editor to view the output file. That will tell you exactly what bytes are being written. IMHO, seeing the actual byte values always has to be the first step when debugging character encoding issues. Don't trust your text editor to be doing the right thing. Don't trust your debugger to be doing the right thing -- unless of course you are looking at byte values in the debugger instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

So ...

- It works (i.e. you can read the accented characters on the output file) if you write them as literal strings.
- It doesn't work when you read them from System.in and then write them.

This suggests that the problem is on the input side.  Specifically, I think your console / keyboard must be using a character encoding for the input stream that does not match the encoding that Java thinks should be used.

You should be able to confirm this tentative diagnosis by outputting the characters you are reading in hexadecimal, and then checking the codes against the unicode tables (which you can find at unicode.org for example).

---

It strikes me as "odd" that the "platform default encoding" appears to be working on the output side, but not the input side.  Maybe someone else can explain ... and offer a concrete suggestion for fixing it.  My gut feeling is that the problem is in the way your keyboard is configured, not in Java or your application.

Comment: Yes, thats basically it, the strange part is that when I read the char from the System.in, it writes it wrongly in the txt, but prints it right in the console, will check the hex codes though.

Comment: Maybe not keyboard, but console settings.

Answer (score 0):

files do not remember their encoding  format, when you look at a .txt, the text editor makes a "best guess" to the encoding used.

if you try to read the file into your program again, the text should be back to normal.

also, try printing the "strange" character directly.

Comment: "Files do not remember their encoding format" Isn't the BOM supposed to serve that purpose (well, assuming they're going to add one)